# Issue with custom Azure IR

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Let me try to explain my doubt. The administrator has created a new Azure IR: General Purpose, 8 cores, 30 minutes of TTL.

The pipeline that I'm testing has two Data Flows: LoadStage_FromFile -> LoadDim_FromStage

I've executed it (manual trigger mode) with the AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime option, and the result was the one I was expecting, 5 minutes on every Data Flow.

I changed the Azure IR to the new one in both Data Flows. However, the time was 2 minutes longer for the first one and about 5 minutes for the second one. In theory, I should have seen a reduction in the overall time, especially for the second job. The details indicate the pipeline was executed using the DefaultIntegrationRuntime (I though I was going to see the name of the custom Azure IR).

[image]

So, I'm sure that I'm missing something, but what could it be? Is there a way to see the configuration for AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime: number of cores, TTL, compute type?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**Last Manual Trigger Execution Test**

[image]

Comment: Open up each of the data flow activity executions by clicking on the eyeglasses next to "activity name".

Note the cluster or compute acquisition time in the top right of the monitoring UX.

That will tell you how long it took to start the cluster.

Comment: Hi, @MarkKromer thanks for your answer. There is something that is not working well, or I'm doing something wrong. But the last test (last image of the post) shows something totally contrary to the theory: the second Data Flow took more time than the first one. Besides, why the result for the pipeline keeps showing 'DefaultIntegrationRuntime (East US)' for the integration runtime. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: A couple of things ... 7 min cluster acquisition is pretty far outside of the norm. You should make an Azure ticket to ADF on that. Databricks clusters are taking too long to form in that case.

Comment: Secondly, ADF is clearly using the default IR in your executions. Are these debug or triggered pipeline executions? In order to re-use the same Azure IR and warm pool, you must explicitly set the IR in the pipeline activity. However, ADF only uses the IR in the activity configuration from pipeline trigger runs. If you are running this from Debug pipeline, you will always use the IR for that debug session.

Comment: Thank you @MarkKromer for your answer. I found a video that helped me to solve this issue. However, I've been doing some tests, and I have noticed some things that generate me more questions about the use and the configuration of the Integration Runtime. But I will put it in another post to keep this focus on just one topic.